# Checkbox vs. menu

Tags: forms, input-fields

I am building a calculator where the user must choose if has has a hybrid car or not.

I was wondering which is better a checkbox - where you check if you have one.

or a menu with yes/no (defaulting in no)

Comment: why not a menu with the types of car, (gas, diesel, with or without hybrid, with or without LPG or pure electric), or is that a bit too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By all means the checkbox. No doubt.
It is *the* widget especially designed for the user to answer yes/no questions.
Also, because it requires a single click to be taken to the desired state, while the menu usually requires more mouse interaction.
It is possible to wrap the checkbox in order to make it look nicer, like in those Apple-like controls, without losing accesibility.
The great advantage of the checkbox for yes/no qustions is that it's universally known.
The problem it has is how difficult is to give it style. There is an offering of checkbox wrappers online to circumvent this issue if it's important to you. I rolled my own.

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes are the preferred control for binary (Yes/No, On/Off, etc.) choices.

Comment: I think so too but how can you be sure? any studies?

Comment: None that I know of, sorry -- only developer docs like Apple's [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-TPXREF198)